# How to make docxtemplater work with angular-fullstack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-fullstack, docxtemplater

i am fairly new to yo generator angular-fullstack. The problem i am facing is that i want to use the docxtemplater with it. I did

```
    npm install docxtemplater --save
```

and

```
    import docxtemplater from 'docxtemplater';
    ...
    angular.module('newApp', [ngCookies, ngResource, ngSanitize, 'btford.socket-io', uiRouter,
      uiBootstrap, _Auth, account, admin, navbar, footer, main, constants, socket, util, testdoc, docxtemplater
    ])
```

in app.js

and used

```
    'use strict';
    const angular = require('angular');

    const uiRouter = require('angular-ui-router');

    var Docxtemplater= require('docxtemplater');

    import routes from './testdoc.routes';

    export class TestdocComponent {
      /*@ngInject*/
      constructor() {
        this.message = 'Hello';

        //loading the file
        var docx=new Docxtemplater().loadFromFile("test.docx");

        //setting the tags
        docx.setTags({"name":"Edgar"});

        //apply the tags
        docx.applyTags();

        //output the docx using dataUri or fs in Node
        docx.output();

      }
    }

    export default angular.module('newApp.testdoc', [uiRouter])
      .config(routes)
      .component('testdoc', {
        template: require('./testdoc.html'),
        controller: TestdocComponent,
        controllerAs: 'testdocCtrl'
      })
      .name;
```

in testdoc.component.js

and i am getting the following error

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module newApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module function Docxtemplater(content, options) due to:
[$injector:strictdi] Docxtemplater is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/strictdi?p0=Docxtemplater

Any solution for this? 
I just need to install this. :(

Also, if this cant work, is there any other library that can generate docx files from templates that can be imported into angular-fullstack?

Comment: Hello Mateen, creator of docxtemplater here. Did you find a way to use docxtemplater ?

Comment: Hey Edi, I didnt find a way so i settled for jspdf instead.

Comment: @edi9999 Haven't found a better way to contact you. I have wrapped Docxtemplater as a Java component. Is that something you'd be interested in for your product? Right now it's very specific and I'm only supporting a limited API such as fill(outputPath, dataAsJson), but my goal wasn't a full port.

Comment: Hello, please continue this conversation by sending a mail to the mail on my github profile : https://github.com/edi9999 . There is no port to Java, but I plan to create an SDK that can talk to a nodejs server that would allow to easily use docxtemplater from many languages (Java, python, C#). Since to get the best performance I think it is better to use v8 rather than rhino.